# JSON formatting with SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, rest, formatting

I would like to format the JSON file shown below into a table.
I get the JSON file from an REST-API.
I already tried to resolve it with OPENJSON and CROSS APPLYS but without success.
There I get only zero values back.
Is there a way to format the JSON file so that it matches the desired result?

Here is the JSON Snippet:

```json
{
   "destination_addresses" :
   [
      "Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland",
      "Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" :
   [
      "Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland"
   ],
   "rows" :
   [
      {
         "elements" :
         [
            {
               "distance" :
               {
                  "text" : "337 km",
                  "value" : 337183
               },
               "duration" :
               {
                  "text" : "3 Stunden, 36 Minuten",
                  "value" : 12968
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" :
               {
                  "text" : "397 km",
                  "value" : 397126
               },
               "duration" :
               {
                  "text" : "4 Stunden, 22 Minuten",
                  "value" : 15692
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The API Output looks like this:

[image: API Output]

The result should be a table that looks like this:

[image: Result]

```
destination_addresses            origin_addresses        distance_text  distance_value           duration_text            duration_value

Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland         Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland   337 km            337183            3 Stunden, 36 Minuten           12968

Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland         Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland   397 km            397126            4 Stunden, 22 Minuten           12968
```

Here is my Cross Apply attempt:

```
SELECT 
    ori.destination_addresses, 
    ele.origin_addresses,
    f.[text], f.[value], 
    dur.[text], 
    dur.[value] 
FROM OPENJSON(@json , '$')
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value)
    with(destination_addresses nvarchar(100),
    origin_addresses nvarchar(max) AS JSON)ori
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(ori.origin_addresses)
    with(origin_addresses nvarchar(100),
    elements nvarchar(max) AS JSON) ele 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(ele.elements)
    with(distance nvarchar(max) AS JSON)dis 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(dis.distance)
    with([text] nvarchar(20),
    [value] numeric,
    duration nvarchar(max) AS JSON)dur 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(dur.duration)
    with([text] nvarchar(20),[value] numeric)f
```

Here is the `Cross Apply` result:

[image: Reuslt]

I am also getting this error msg.

> The JSON text is not formatted properly. The unexpected character "O" was found at position 0.

Comment: *All* content in your posts should be in English; that *includes* the title.

Comment: *"I already tried to resolve it with OPENJSON and CROSS APPLYS [sic] but without success"* You forgot to include those attempts in your question.

Comment: It doesn't look like this has anything to do with formatting. The desired screenshot shows individual tables. Is the *real* question how to *parse and transform* the JSON string into a table?

Comment: Please explain the *parsing* logic by which 5 addresses and 2 elements become 3 rows. It's quite possible that the data should be transformed before it's inserted into the database. There's no implied order in SQL, the language, which means trying to match addresses and elements by index may be *very* hard. The JSON text itself doesn't imply any relation between addresses and elements.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right, I only partially shortened the json for the post and not completely. Now it should fit. I have also adjusted the result.

Comment: Post the queries and expected results as text, not images. Images can't be copied, executed and tested. What you want should be done *before* importing the data into the database though. Just to get the array index for addresses and elements you have to use OPENJSON without a schema, which makes it a lot harder to access individual properties in the elements, durations. I hope you only want this for a one-off conversion to a real table, because the query will be very slow

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes it would be a one time thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to parse the JSON text and create the desired rows *before* inserting it into the database. You could try to use this query BUT it's VERY fragile :

```
SELECT 
    d.value as destination_address,
    o.value as origin_address,
    Distance_Text ,
    Distance_Value,
    Duration_Text ,
    Duration_Value
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json,'$.destination_addresses') d,
    OPENJSON(@json,'$.origin_addresses')  o,
    OPENJSON(@json,'$.rows')  r 
    cross apply openjson(r.value,'$.elements') e
    cross apply openjson(e.value) with ( 
        Distance_Text  nvarchar(20) '$.distance.text',
        Distance_Value integer      '$.distance.value',
        Duration_Text  nvarchar(20) '$.duration.text',
        Duration_Value integer      '$.duration.value'
    ) a
where d.[key]=e.[key]
```

The JSON text itself has problems. It seems that destination and actual element values must be matched by index, BUT elements are contained in a `rows` array. What happens if there are multiple rows? Or multiple destinations?

The `key` column returned by `OPENJSON` without a schema contains the array index. This can be used to somehow match destination and element data by index, assuming there's only one row.

If there are several rows, `e.Key` can't be used to JOIN with destination addresses, as it contains the element index inside a single row only.

If each `row` corresponds to a single origin address we could use a join between `o.Key` and `r.Key` to map rows to origins :

```
where d.[key]=e.[key] and o.[key]=r.[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in reality the json you have is an array of elements rather than one. If not so, you can remove one level of OPENJSON.
I also assume there's always one origin address.

```sql
select  ad.value as destination_address, json_value(x.value,'$.origin_addresses[0]') as origin_address, d.*
from openjson(N'[{
   "destination_addresses" :
   [
      "Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland",
      "Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" :
   [
      "Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland"
   ],
   "rows" :
   [
      {
         "elements" :
         [
            {
               "distance" :
               {
                  "text" : "337 km",
                  "value" : 337183
               },
               "duration" :
               {
                  "text" : "3 Stunden, 36 Minuten",
                  "value" : 12968
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" :
               {
                  "text" : "397 km",
                  "value" : 397126
               },
               "duration" :
               {
                  "text" : "4 Stunden, 22 Minuten",
                  "value" : 15692
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}]') x
cross apply openjson(x.value, '$.destination_addresses') ad
cross apply OPENJSON(x.value, '$.rows[0].elements') el
cross apply OPENJSON(el.value) with (
    distanceText nvarchar(100) '$.distance.text'
,   distanceValue bigint '$.distance.value'
,   durationText nvarchar(100) '$.duration.text'
,   durationValue bigint '$.duration.value'
,   status varchar(100) '$.status'  
    ) d
where el.[key] = ad.[key]
```

I split the json by destination addresses, and then split the rows the same way. `where el.[key] = ad.[key]` makes sure each row from the addresses element matchings corresponding row of "rows".

Output:

| destination_address | origin_address | distanceText | distanceValue | durationText | durationValue | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland | Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland | 337 km | 337183 | 3 Stunden, 36 Minuten | 12968 | OK |
| Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland | Straße ohne Straßennamen, 99999 Ort, Deutschland | 397 km | 397126 | 4 Stunden, 22 Minuten | 15692 | OK |